MPAndroidChart bar width change on re draw the chart?
I am using MPAndroidChart bar chart, to display data from cursor, and I have tabs used like filter, so whenever I choose different tab the data changes and I redraw the bar chart. At first draw everything is fine but when re-draw the width of the bar gets larger to the extent that only one bar displays on the visible screen.image 1 - everything is fineimage 2 - choosing another data filter, also everything is fineimage 3 - now when I choose the first tab again the width gets larger and takes the whole visible space
here is my code:
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(@NonNull Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        int loaderId = loader.getId();
        if (data != null && data.getCount() != 0) {
            switch (loaderId) {
                case ONE_DAY_LOADER:
                                   
                        barDataSet = new BarDataSet(createChartData(data),"");
                        barData = new BarData(barDataSet);
                        barChart.setData(barData);
                        barChart.setFitBars(false);
                        styleChart();            
                        break;

 private ArrayList<BarEntry> createChartData(Cursor cursor) {
        ArrayList<BarEntry> values = new ArrayList<>();
        itemAxis = new ArrayList<>();
        itemValues = new String[]{};
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        do    {
            int steps = arrayIndex+1;
            int categoryIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(category);
            String mCategory = cursor.getString(categoryIndex);
            Log.d(ExpensesStatistics.class.getSimpleName(), "mCategory: "+mCategory);
            itemAxis.add(mCategory);
            itemValues = itemAxis.toArray(new String[arrayIndex]);
            arrayIndex++;
            int moneyPaidIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("total");
            float notRoundedMoneyPaid = cursor.getFloat(moneyPaidIndex);
            float roundedMoneyPayed = DateExtractionAndPriceFormat.floatRound(notRoundedMoneyPaid,2);
            values.add(new BarEntry(steps,roundedMoneyPayed));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

        return values;
    }
    private void styleChart() {
        ValueFormatter formatter = new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getAxisLabel(float value, AxisBase axis) {

                try {
                    int index = (int) (value-0.7);
                    return itemAxis.get(index);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "";
                }
            }
        };
        RoundedBarChartRenderer roundedBarChartRenderer =
                new RoundedBarChartRenderer(barChart , barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler());

        roundedBarChartRenderer.setRadius(20);
        barChart.setRenderer(roundedBarChartRenderer);
        barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(3);
        barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(formatter);
        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawLabels(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawLabels(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(false);
        barChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(11.0f);
        barChart.getXAxis().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        barChart.getXAxis().setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        barChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
        barChart.getXAxis().setYOffset(0.0f);
        barChart.setExtraOffsets(8.0f,8.0f,8.0f,8.0f);
        barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        if (context!=null) {
            barChart.getXAxis().setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sub_text_color, null));
            barDataSet.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sub_text_color, null));
            barDataSet.setValueTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sub_text_color, null));
        }
        barDataSet.setValueTextSize(11.0f);
        barDataSet.setValueTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        barChart.invalidate();
    }

I have tried to set the bar width programmatically like barData.setBarWidth(0.5f);
but it didn't work. I expect image number 3 to be the same as image number 1

Please take the time to provide a minimum complete example, that someone else could easily run to see the same issue as you. There isn't enough information here to tell what might be missing.
